# sparksql with dataset of several GBs size

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I didn't found the answer for this question in the web or other questions, so I'm trying here:

- The size of my dataset is several GB's (~5GB to ~15GB).
- I have multiple tables, some of them contains ~50M rows
- I'm using `postgresSQL` which has it's own query optimization (parallel workers and indexing).
- 50% of my queries take advantages the indexing and multiple workers to finish the query faster.
- Some of my queries use `join` command

I read that sparkSQL intends to run on huge datasets.

1. If I have multiple servers to run sparkSQL on, can I get better performance with `sparkSQL` ?
2. Does 15GB of datasets fit to work with `sparkSQL` or `postgresSQL` ?
3. When it will be best to choose `sparkSQL` over `postgresSQL` ?

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question without more information about the structure of your data and the type of queries you are planning to do on the dataset. The size of your data in GB has no meaning for a database alone, what we need to know is how many rows it represents. Are updates/inserts planned and if yes how often.

Comment: I add more info (number of rows in table - ~50M)

Comment: Will you need to do JOINS with several tables in your queries? What about the INSERTs/UPDATEs ?

Comment: yes, I'm using join, insert and update commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If I have multiple servers to run sparkSQL on, can I get better performance with sparkSQL ?

-> If your data does not havea lot of skew, SparkSQL will give better performance in terms of query speeds as the query wold run on the spark cluster.

2. Does 15GB of datasets fit to work with sparkSQL or postgresSQL ?

-> SparkSQL is simply a Query Engine that is built into Apache Spark so it will process the data, and will allow you to create Views in-memory but that is it. Once the Application terminates, the view is removed.
PostgreSQL, on teh other hand is a, and I quote, a **DATABASE**. It will let you query data and store the results in its own native format.

Now coming to your question, 15GB of Data is **not a lot** to process for wither of the Engines, and your query performance would depend upon the data model.

3. When it will be best to choose sparkSQL over postgresSQL ?

-> Choose SparkSQL, when you wish to perform AD-HOC queries, and the dataset sizes range in the TeraByte range.
Choose PostgreSQL, when you wish to store transactional data, or datasets that are simply being used to drive BI tools, custom UIs or Applications.

Comment: What do you mean: "If your data does not havea lot of skew" ? can you give example ?

Comment: Data Skew means the distribution of data records is non uniform in the entire dataset. It’s direct impact is poor load balancing in parallel processing environments.

Comment: One more question: spark can be faster, because it save it's data on RAM vs postgresSQL which first need to get the data from disk and after it run query on ram  ?

Comment: Like I said, if your data model is efficient, PostgreSQL would perform absolutely fine. As for the memory thing, Databases such as PostgreSQL can run queries more efficiently if data in the tables in indexed. Spark can be faster in scenarios where Data skew is not a major impacting factor. Also Spark does spill over records to disk if it runs out of memory

Comment: You can read more on Spark Tuning on its official documentation.